# How to handle a longer wait time for complex queries? Angularjs

Tags: sql, angularjs, timeout, breeze

I am using angularjs, breeze, mssql2012.

I have several queries that takes about 40 seconds to 1 minute to complete running. It is a search function that goes through several tables with records above 900K with several joins.

It shows up with a few errors:

- 500 (Internal Server Error)
- [Error] Error retrieving dataThe wait
  operation timed out Error: The wait operation timed out

**I am not sure whether the error is with breeze or angular, but I'd like to make the wait time longer than a minute. The query does work on the server.**

I've tried using the $timeout from angular, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
getSearch().then(function () {
            common.$timeout(function () {
                toggleSearchSpinner();
            }, 1250);
        });
```

Not quite sure how to use the timeout function.

I do have $timeout defined in the common module:

```
commonModule.factory('common',
    ['$q', '$rootScope', '$timeout', 'commonConfig', 'logger', common]);
 function common($q, $rootScope, $timeout, commonConfig, logger) {
    var throttles = {};

    var service = {
        // common angular dependencies
        $broadcast: $broadcast,
        $q: $q,
        $timeout: $timeout,
    };
    return service;
}
```

I have multiple places in the application where queries might just take a long time and unfortunately it is unavoidable. It would be great if there was a one time setting that prolongs the timeout wait time.... Is there?

Comment: Go to browser console and look at server response - then u can say 100%  is it client timeout or server. 99% that it is server, never heard anything about timeout in angular.

Comment: The timeout is definitely from the server. You can  define it on the `DbContext` or in the connection string.